# Multi axis plot problem with appearance

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a problem with the appearance of a mutli axis plot...

Currently I have the following: [image: Current situation]

However I do not want the arrow in the right y-axis but from the documentation I read that the * in the  `axis y line` command should prevent this... but it doesn't. Further the upper axis, where the second x axis would appear, is now gray I however want it to be black. Hopefully someone knows the right commands to fix this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}                                                      
\usepackage{graphics,siunitx}                                                   
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}                                                      
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                             
\pgfplotsset{%                                                                  
  compat=1.6,                                                                   
  width=10cm,                                                                   
  height=7cm,                                                                   
  scale only axis,                                                              
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},        
  xmajorgrids,                                                                  
  xminorgrids,                                                                  
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},     
  ymajorgrids,                                                                     
  yminorgrids                                                                   
}                                                                               

\begin{axis}[%                                                                  
xmin=0, xmax=40000,                                                             
xlabel={Time},                                                                  
ymin=-50, ymax=50,                                                              
ylabel={Power},                                                                 
axis y line*=left,                                                              
axis x line*=bottom]                                                            
\addplot [                                                                      
color=red,                                                                      
solid                                                                           
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0};                                                              
\label{pcharge}                                                                 
\addplot [                                                                      
color=green,                                                                    
solid                                                                           
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0)};                                                             
\label{pbattery}                                                                
\end{axis}                                                                      

\begin{axis}[%                                                                  
xmin=0, xmax=40000,                                                             
ymin=0, ymax=100,                                                               
ylabel={State of charge},                                                       
axis lines=left,                                                                
axis y line*=right,                                                             
axis x line=none,                                                               
legend style={at={(1.15,1)},anchor=north west,nodes=right}]                     

\addplot [                                                                      
color=blue,                                                                     
solid
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0)};                                                             
\addlegendentry{$SOC$};                                                         

\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=pcharge}\addlegendentry{$P_\mathrm{charge}$};
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=pbattery}\addlegendentry{$P_\mathrm{battery}$};
\end{axis}                                                                      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also want to consider `\pgfplotsset{use layers}` right after your `\begin{tikzpicture}[..]` statement(s) -- this improves multi-axis-plots.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you issued `axis lines=left` before `axis y line*=right`. If you remove `axis lines=left`, the arrow disappears. This looks like a bug, so you might want to file a bug report.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}                                                      
\usepackage{graphics,siunitx}                                                   
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}                                                      
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                             
\pgfplotsset{%                                                                  
  compat=1.6,                                                                   
  width=10cm,                                                                   
  height=7cm,                                                                   
  scale only axis,                                                              
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},        
  xmajorgrids,                                                                  
  xminorgrids,                                                                  
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},     
  ymajorgrids,                                                                     
  yminorgrids                                                                   
}                                                                               

\begin{axis}[%                                                                  
xmin=0, xmax=40000,                                                             
xlabel={Time},                                                                  
ymin=-50, ymax=50,                                                              
ylabel={Power},                                                                 
axis y line*=left,                                                              
axis x line*=bottom]                                                            
\addplot [                                                                      
color=red,                                                                      
solid                                                                           
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0)};                                                              
\label{pcharge}                                                                 
\addplot [                                                                      
color=green,                                                                    
solid                                                                           
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0)};                                                             
\label{pbattery}                                                                
\end{axis}                                                                      

\begin{axis}[%                                                                  
xmin=0, xmax=40000,                                                             
ymin=0, ymax=100,                                                               
ylabel={State of charge},                                                                     
axis y line*=right,                                                             
axis x line=none,                                                               
legend style={at={(1.15,1)},anchor=north west,nodes=right}]                     
\addplot [                                                                      
color=blue,                                                                     
solid
]                                                                               
coordinates{(0,0)};                                                             
\addlegendentry{$SOC$};                                                         

\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=pcharge}\addlegendentry{$P_\mathrm{charge}$};
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=pbattery}\addlegendentry{$P_\mathrm{battery}$};
\end{axis}                                                                      
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Further any know how, how to make the top line to black? Normally when I use these settings for axis style a all the outer lines are black.

Comment: @WG-: That happens because you're setting `axis x line*=bottom` for both axes, which means the top line isn't drawn. If you remove the option from the first axis and set `xmajorgrids=false` for the second, it should work.